# guzzlehttp запрос выдает ошибку "Connection refused for URI"

Tags: php, guzzle

Взял пример из документации. Этот пример работает, на других серверах. На моем локальном сервере. Я думаю, чтобы он не работал надо постараться.(

```
$token = "my token";
$secret = "my secret";
$dadata = new \Dadata\DadataClient($token, $secret);
$response = $dadata->clean("address", "мск сухонская 11 89");
```

А в ответ мне приходит ошибка,

"Connection refused for URI [https://cleaner.dadata.ru/api/v1/clean/address"](https://cleaner.dadata.ru/api/v1/clean/address%22)

Я думаю это связано с настройками сервера. Но я не знаю какие. Может кто нибудь сталкивался с такой ошибкой?

p.s. у нас стоит php7.4 и Apache 2.4.38

Дополнение:

Я наверное не совсем корректный пример привел. Этот класс "\Dadata\DadataClient" вызывает библиотеку guzzle. И потому можно упростить пример.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle'); 
echo $response->getStatusCode(); 
echo $response->getHeaderLine('content-type'); 
echo $response->getBody();
```

И ошибка
"Connection refused for URI api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle"

#0 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(35): GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler->__invoke()

#1 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(31): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke()

#2 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/RedirectMiddleware.php(71): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}()

#3 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(63): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke()

#4 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/HandlerStack.php(75): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}()

#5 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(331): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke()

#6 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(168): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer()

#7 /usr/share/php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php(187): GuzzleHttp\Client->requestAsync()

#8 /usr/share/evanti/evanti-cms-bitch/admin/controllers/ClientController.php(426): GuzzleHttp\Client->request()

#9 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516): ClientController->viewAction()

#10 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch()

#11 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch()

#12 /usr/share/php/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(105): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()

#13 /usr/share/php/Zend/Application.php(384): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()

#14 /var/www/admin-public/index.php(52): Zend_Application->run()

Заранее спасибо.